How to create a proudct and variant in Craft commerce 5?
I am getting json object of product that needs to created in Craft Comemrce 5 but it is creating a product but failing create variant. I tried with below approaches but no luck

Save product then try to save variant
Create product and variant at same time $product->setVariants([$variant]);

Below is my code -
$product = new Product();
    $product->typeId = $data['typeId']; // Product type ID
    $product->title = 'Test';   // Product title
    $product->enabled = $data['enabled'] ?? true; // Enabled status
    $product->productDescription = $data['description'] ?? ''; // Description
    $product->postDate = new \DateTime();
    if (!\Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a single default variant
    $variant = new Variant();
    $variant->productId = $product->id;
    $variant->sku = "ABCD"; // SKU for the variant
    $variant->price = 10.01; // Price
    // $variant->stock = 1; // Stock level
    $variant->hasUnlimitedStock = false; // Manage stock
    $variant->isDefault = true; // Mark as default variant
    $variant->availableForPurchase = true;
    $variant->promotable = true;
    $variant->taxCategoryId = 1;
    $variant->shippingCategoryId = 1;

    if (!\Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($variant)) {
        // dd($product->getErrors());
        // \Craft::error('Failed to save product with variants: ' . json_encode($product->getErrors()), __METHOD__);
        return false;
    }

    $product->setVariants([$variant]);
    if (!\Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product)) {
        Craft::error('Failed to save product with variants: ' . json_encode($product->getErrors()), __METHOD__);
        return false;
    }

Also, I want to store stock as well but I am getting error that stock is read only attribute.
